# HTML custom @font-face not displaying correct font

Tags: html, css, font-face

i've downloaded a custom font in ttf format, i want to override my bootstrap font for a header text.

I've added it in my CSS.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'BrauerNeue';
  src: url(brauerneue.ttf);
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'BrauerNeue';
}
```

Then added a h1 in my page:

```
<h1>Text</h1>
```

It still displays in the bootstrap font.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: If your stylesheet with the h1{font family} is above the bootstrap css file, then it will take the bootstrap one assuming both selectors are equally specific

Comment: Use [font squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) to get a proper kit, be aware of the license.

Comment: Is this an external style sheet? The font is in the same file as the css file?  Another thing to think about, is the bootstrap h1 selector more specific than your selector?

Answer (score 0):

Check the URL. If all is correct, then:

```
h1 {
    font-family: "BrauerNeue" !important;
}
```